# Two Notifications Suggestion

Tags: feature-request, comment, notifications, bookmarks

Sometimes I find some interesting questions That I like to read their answers. But I lost the question and forget the title of it. So I can't access it anymore...

I Suggest that M.S.E notify users (It can be an option for everyone like it) for answers on their favorite(Starred) questions.

The Second suggestion is notifications on Vote Up for you comments. sometimes you answer a question in a comment instead of a post. Notifications can  facilitate accessing to you previous answers...

Thanks.

Comment: If you view your [favorites tab sorted by activity](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/195683/axolotl?tab=favorites&sort=activity) does it not show there? Assuming you starred it. I may be wrong, but I think most actions on my past favorites result in a marker on the favorites tab. Clearly visible whenever I view my profile.

Comment: This past post seems similar to one of your feature requests: [A way to “watch” questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6994) You might also have a look at other posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6994).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The activity tab also a number of favorite posts where "something happened", although usually when I see that number I am not entirely sure what exactly. Related older posts: [What does the number next to favorites mean?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3754) and [Favorites tab claims there was activity, but doesn't tell me where](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12622).

Comment: @Martin It is somewhat of a mystery what exactly is counted to me also. I am, in a sense, relieved to learn that you aren't totally sure either. Anyway, if there is a new answer, it will certainly show.